# Click and drag selection box in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp

Is it possible to implement mouse click and drag selection box in GridView UWP Windows 10. Should it be done through simply drawing a rectangle, calculating coordinates of its points and evaluating position of other objects inside this box? Or are there some other ways?

Could you give a bit of sample code or a link?

Comment: Depends on what kind of items do you want to select? List items, or items in a canvas, or something else?

Comment: @MartinZikmund for GridView

Comment: I am not to clear with your issue, please clarify what is the effect you want to implement? Whether you want to drag items in the Gridview or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The Universal Windows Platform does allow for Drag-And-Drop behavior. This includes drag from app and drop outside of app, drag and drop inside the app, and drag from outside the app and drop in the app.

The way to do this very simple (with room for heavy customization if you feel like it is needed): UWP XAML controls have a `CanDrag` and `AllowDrop` properties. The former is just a property of whichever control you're dealing with, the latter is an event that needs to be handled properly via code. If you want to further customize your app you can also handle the `DragOver`, which handles behavior when a dragged item is over a drop area but has not been "released" yet.

For further details and a bit example code please read [Microsoft's own documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/drag-and-drop) for Drag-And-Drop. For a more built up example, you can check out the following [Github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop).

Comment: it's not drag and drop , dragable rectangle selection ,